# Timed sliding text-box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to animate my text box so that it slides into frame from the right side at (x) amount of time. So far, I haven't found any online resources that could help me with this animation.

For now, I just have a simple (absolute) box.

```css
.taskbox {
  width: 230px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="taskbox">Evidently, the pandemic has taken a toll on the economy! You should find a way to financially stay afloat. Humans have something called 'stipends' to aide in a situation like this. We should <a href="a2_page_3.html">investigate</a>!</div>
```

Note: Not too sure if this will require JavaScript, but I have preexisting functions for elements not involved in my question. If my script is needed, I'm more than happy to update my post.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For sure it won't required java but it could have required javascript ;-)

Comment: @CedricCholley would the code change if the box was located elsewhere? For example, I have another page that I'd like to have the same animation on. However, the text box is located on the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: it depends… if at the end the new box has the same `left` position the code can stay the same (the top / bottom part doesn't matter). If the `left` position has changed then you'll need to adapt the value in the animation. This can be easily done with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with CSS only with [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) you can specify a duration as well as a delay (in your case x). Paradoxically to make an element slide from the right it easier to positioned it with the `left` property. Like so…

```css
.taskbox {
  width: 230px;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: slide-from-right .4s 2s forwards; /* x = 2s */
}

@keyframes slide-from-right {
  to {
    left: calc(100% - 230px - 30px - 25px);
    /* 100% = total width, 230px = element width, 30px = left and right padding, 25px = distance from right border */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="taskbox">Evidently, the pandemic has taken a toll on the economy! You should find a way to financially stay afloat. Humans have something called 'stipends' to aide in a situation like this. We should <a href="a2_page_3.html">investigate</a>!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could animate `transform: translate`:

```css
.taskbox {
  width: 230px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: courier new;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: translate3d(calc(100% + 25px), 0, 0);
  animation: slide-in 0.5s 1s cubic-bezier(0.3, 1.3, 0.9, 1) forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="taskbox">Evidently, the pandemic has taken a toll on the economy! You should find a way to financially stay afloat. Humans have something called 'stipends' to aide in a situation like this. We should <a href="a2_page_3.html">investigate</a>!</div>
```

In case you're wondering why I'm using `translate3d`, it triggers hardware acceleration. [Check out this article if you're interested](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-hardware-acceleration-css-animations/).